# PHP custom sort on an object array Laravel-5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I need to build a custom sort on an object array but i'm not sure where to start.  I've seen the functions usort() etc but I can't see how i'd implement these functions for what I require.

My application is returning the below object array.  I need to order it by the "slot" field in the following order: All Day, Morning, Afternoon.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\BookingDates Object
                (
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 265
                            [slot] => Morning
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 265
                            [slot] => Morning
              )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [1] => App\BookingDates Object
                (
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 266
                            [slot] => Afternoon
                      )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 266
                            [slot] => Afternoon
                      )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [2] => App\BookingDates Object
                (
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 267
                            [slot] => All Day
                       )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 267
                            [slot] => All Day
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

The result i'm looking for is this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\BookingDates Object
                (
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 267
                            [slot] => All Day
                       )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 267
                            [slot] => All Day
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [1] => App\BookingDates Object
                (
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 265
                            [slot] => Morning
                      )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 265
                            [slot] => Morning
                      )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [2] => App\BookingDates Object
                (
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [table:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 266
                            [slot] => Afternoon
                       )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 266
                            [slot] => Afternoon
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [casts:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: And what you have tried post your attempts too

Comment: I have not made attempts yet, so looking for suggestions how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
public function index()
{
  $bookingsDate = BookingDate::all() // Your actual collection
  $this->sortCollection($bookingDate);
}
public function sortCollection(\Collection &$bookingDate)
{
   $bookingDate->sortBy(function($date)
   {
     $slots = [
        'Afternoon' => 1,
        'Morning'   => 2,
        'All day'   => 3,
     ];

     $slot = $slots[$date['slot']];


     return $slot;
   });
}
```

The sortBy method will do an ascending sort, for descending sort, try sortByDesc

See : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby